# Why casting an array with (array) cause the array items to not be updated?

Tags: php, arrays

Why does casting `$arr` with `(array)` cause the array items to not be modified?

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ((array)$arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
```

`$arr` should now equal [2,4,6,8] but for some reason it still equals [1,2,3,4].

Comment: Note: without `(array)`, the original array is modified ( https://repl.it/repls/IllfatedBlueBetatest )

Comment: Hypothesis: The `(array)` cast is a conversion that results in a *new* array, and modifications to such array are not visible to the original array // Test: https://repl.it/repls/ShamelessIllfatedFactorial // Conclusion: hypothesis holds.

Comment: Think about it like this : `$arr = [1,2,3,4]; $newarr = (array) $arr; $newarr[] = 5; print_r($arr);` You wouldn't expect `$arr` to have the new `5` entry, because `$newarr = (array) $arr` didn't change `$arr` to an array, it set `$newarr` to whatever `$arr` would be if cast as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not modifying the original array, rather, the current looped iteration. If you wanted to modify the original array, you'd need to access the keys:

```
foreach ((array) $arr as $k => $v) {
    $arr[$k] = $v * 2;
}
```

It is possible to update the original by ['passing by reference'](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) as confirmed by [@user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740) and the example that [they](https://repl.it/repls/QuarterlyGratefulAssociate) have provided.

Thirdly, as [@user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740) pointed out in the original comment chain, using `(array)` seems to cause it to create a new array.

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/TangibleSimultaneousLearning)

Comment: PHP *does* modify "array variables", normally. The question is specific about the cast.

Comment: @user2864740 thanks for the confirmation, I'll update the post.

Comment: Here is the counter-case REPL (notice that there is no `(array)`) - https://repl.it/repls/IllfatedBlueBetatest

Comment: @user2864740 thank you very much, you beat me to it. I have updated the post with the relevant information.